# Why the openssl output differs for SHA512 Digest

Tags: openssl

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo -n "Password" | openssl sha512
(stdin)= 90bf10f0985a74a1be02f5704c3473dbcd9b2d4dd0968169b58f75ba60174efb42117478694a3219cee0cee93f8e04743c2b17445bcdf921857e44604b2a764f

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo "Password" | openssl dgst -sha512
(stdin)= 1b0f2ea6c7d600da96a57281a87f382ab3d9cd04d5a00e895689ae5431d43787e92392fa35f9bbeae9ace0f96e2e7b10fa762db8b690ccced419c04c10ffc694

Answer (score -1, accepted):

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo -n "Password" | openssl dgst -sha512
(stdin)= 90bf10f0985a74a1be02f5704c3473dbcd9b2d4dd0968169b58f75ba60174efb42117478694a3219cee0cee93f8e04743c2b17445bcdf921857e44604b2a764f

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo -n "Password" | openssl sha512
(stdin)= 90bf10f0985a74a1be02f5704c3473dbcd9b2d4dd0968169b58f75ba60174efb42117478694a3219cee0cee93f8e04743c2b17445bcdf921857e44604b2a764f

C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: Typo error -n was missing.